# Upgraded WP7 app to WP8. The thread 0xb6c has exited with code 259 (0x103)

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

After upgrading our WP7 app to WP8, the app stops working (as in just halts and none of the ui elements work) almost immediately after the splash screen.

The only output seems to be this: 'The thread 0xb6c has exited with code 259 (0x103).'.

How do I go about debugging this problem? The app works perfectly on WP7.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like there may be some errors in your configuration. Make sure that you have a `Navigation page` in your `WMAppManifest` file.

If you do, then check if your namespaces are correct and your project directory names have not been modified so that all resources (file paths, app name etc..) within the `csproj` file point to valid paths. If you've renamed the solution, or any namespaces, you have to ensure that those changes are reflected throughout the project files.

If none of that works, try creating a new solution and importing your project (create any relevant backups first) and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have double checked this just in case, but everything looks to be fine in the WMAppManifest.

I believe this may be related to my other question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15660741/httpwebrequest-begingetresponse-callback-not-firing-on-wp8-working-on-wp7

Do you know if any of the code in that post could cause a problem like this? If I comment out the call to create the HTTPRequest, the app will run and the UI does not lock up.

Comment: I haven't come across that issue. Does it work on a WP8 device rather than the emulator?